# If statement Calculation that includes nulls and checks for prefix

Tags: if-statement, tableau-desktop

This is for tableau calculated field, but the code is common for any excel or literally anything. Please help its just a simple if statement but with multiple conditions.

> **I am trying to count a distinct number of customers with a few conditions**

1. customers the with 'ABC' prefix and repeat order = no should be included in this metric
2. Two customer numbers should be disregarded from the total count
3. - all other customers (regardless of prefix or repeat order selection)
4. Delivered date should not be null

> **Below is my calculation**

```
COUNTD(
    IF NOT ISNULL([Delivered Date]) 
    AND (
            (STARTSWITH([Customer ID],"ABC") AND [Repeat order]="No")
                 OR NOT STARTSWITH([Customer ID],"ABC") )
    AND NOT ([Customer ID] IN ("ABC-AA2517","ABC-CO1325"))
    THEN 
        [Customer ID] 
    END
)
```

> **Numbers**

```
-Overall, I have 11282 customers with a date.
---2239 customers have ABC prefixes. 
---Among which 1577 is yes for repeat order and 662 is no for the repeat order.
```

So the total number for this metric should be 11282-1577-the 2 disregarded customer numbers.
**The final number should be 9703, but it shows 8599 as the total.**

I think its not include those 660 customers. Not sure what mistake I am making in the calculation.

Comment: I can almost guarantee a formula in excel to do this will not work in Tableau.  They are not as similar as you would think.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you suggest the updates to if statement. Sorry I thought it might be the same excel calculations and calculated fields

Comment: First question - does your data source have exactly one row per [Customer ID]? or are there multiple rows with the same [Customer ID]? if customer ID is a unique column in the input data, you improve the efficiency of your query by using COUNT() instead of COUNTD()

Comment: Second comment - your calculation looks correct on the surface - although you could simplify all the startsWith logic a bit  by removing the first "StartsWith([Customer ID], "ABC") AND". Its redundant given the next line

Comment: Recommended approach - make a short copy of your data set, simplify as much as possible, and reproduce the problem on a small set of rows, then you can drill down and see which row was excluded that you expected should have been included - and finally then diagnose why

Comment: Thank you for the steps @AlexBlakemore. I will investigate. I found a work around to display the numbers I need, so closing this question. I really appreciate the time you have spent to explain